# Wordpress website source shows lots of back slashes

Tags: html, wordpress

I was looking at the source for this website http://perfoto.com when I noticed that the HTML contains over 1MB of data that is mostly the back slash character (`\`) hidden in a `<script>` tag.

My question is - What is the purpose of the back slashes? Is it some sort of hack or just extraneous code?

Comment: Forward slash is / not \

Comment: That looks like an accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on that site is broken. If you take a close look at the code, the jQuery function around those slashes isn't complete and does not run.

Simple answer, there is no purpose.

Here is the code with the slashes removed:

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script%5
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s0.wp.com/wp-content/js/devicepx-jetpack.js?ver=201316'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found this [bug report](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/backslashes-being-added-in-latest-version-also-428) that seems to point to an issue with the Google Analytics WordPress plugin.